# How to consume messages from Apache Kafka which is third party using AWS services

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka

We have a third party Apache Kafka producer which is on premise. We need to read message from third party kafka component into AWS using AWS services and triggering lambda function. What approach should be taken to consume message from kafka in AWS

Answer (score 4):

You have a few options. You could just schedule a lambda call every few seconds and read from the kafka topic using your favourite language. That is quite simple and depending on the data volume you are getting, it might be good enough.

Alternatively, you can install a [community contributed kafka connector for lambda](https://github.com/Nordstrom/kafka-connect-lambda), and just invoke lambda directly.

Or you can use the [awslabs kafka connector for Kinesis](https://github.com/awslabs/kinesis-kafka-connector), that relays messages from Kafka into Kinesis data streams or kinesis firehose, where you can use lambda natively.